# Force Log4Net to output specific events

Tags: c#, log4net

I use log4net for diagnostic logging in my applications, that is, if log4net doesn't work, the application runs fine anyway.
I have a separate Audit Trail log that will block the application if the audit trail fails.

I want to include Audit Trail messages in my log4net logs, but I have a conundrum: I want the AuditTrail messages to be output with the highest priority (Critical like), but I don't want the audit trail messages to be represented as fatal errors.
They should be emitted with an INFO level, given they are not critical errors, but simply mandatory messages.

I was looking into the internals of log4net and I stumbled upon the protected `Logger.Forcedlog` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new logging event and logs the event without further checks.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logEvent">The event being logged.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// Delivers the logging event to the attached appenders.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
protected virtual void ForcedLog(LoggingEvent logEvent)
{
  logEvent.EnsureRepository((ILoggerRepository) this.Hierarchy);
  this.CallAppenders(logEvent);
}
```

I can call this method via reflection and bypass any level check, but I'm feeling very guilty.

Are there any "cleaner" alternatives?

Comment: Why don't you use a separate logger dedicated to audit trail that you set to INFO level?

Comment: Because the log4net settings are managed in a file editable for every installation, and I have no guarantees about the levels enabled on it.

Comment: So we are talking about actual Applications that are installed on-site, not cloud, right?

Comment: Yep! I have many installations, on premise of my customers. Every log could be configured differently, and I want to make sure that this kind of messages gets logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a named logger, e.g. `AuditLog`, with or without an explicit configuration in the `log4net` settings.
By default this logger will inherit the log level from the root logger or a configured one.

Just after where you apply the `log4net` configuration, you configure/overrule that specific logger with the (minimal) log level you need.

You apply the configuration, e.g. from a file.

```
var repository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

Immediately after the above configuration, you change the log level of the `AuditLog` logger programmatically, e.g. to `Info`.

```
var auditLog = repository.GetLogger("AuditLog") as Logger;
auditLog.Level = log4net.Core.Level.Info;
```

Anywhere in your application when you log via this `AuditLog` logger, its programmatically set level will be considered. The below call to log an informational message will pass as it fulfills  the `Info` log level that has been set.

```
var auditLog = LogManager.GetLogger("AuditLog");
auditLog.Info("Hello audit trail log!");
```

---

An example.
Given the configuration below, where the log level is `Off`, the `AuditLog` logger will still log to the configured `FileAppender`.
Any other loggers will not, because of the `Off` setting.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="log-file.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="Off" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pfx for the idea, what ended up working for me was in fact declaring a custom log level.
Given it's not exactly what I was requesting, I'm rewarding the answer to pfx, but I'm reporting my solution here in case it could help someone else:

```cs
// declares a custom Log4Net Level named Audit with the same priority of Fatal errors
private static readonly Level AuditTrailLevel = new Level(Level.Fatal.Value, "AUDIT");

// to be used as:
_log.Logger.Log(null, AuditTrailLevel, message, exception);
```

Sweet and simple!